Express with Node Js and TS App request specific header info brings the whole server response
kind of exploring new things with node js and express with typescript using a class approach.
In a specific component in app and trying to retrieve a specifc header settled on postman in order to do further actions ...but I´m receiving the whole server response type structure...but not working...
Did try with the approach
request.header("my-custom-header")

                
this brings the whole server response type object


or
request.headers["my-custom-header"] / request.get("my-custom-header")...(this one according to Express docs

none of these working bringing undefined

thus im not sure how to proceed in here.
To check the headers are already coming i did this test logs, throwing the ServerResponse type headers object like this:
my token <ref *2> ServerResponse {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  outputData: [],
  outputSize: 0,
  writable: true,
  destroyed: false,
  _last: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: true,
  maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
  _defaultKeepAlive: true,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
  sendDate: true,
  _removedConnection: false,
  _removedContLen: false,
  _removedTE: false,
  strictContentLength: false,
  _contentLength: null,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: false,
  _headerSent: false,
  _closed: false,
  socket: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      constructed: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      dataEmitted: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Function: socketOnError],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      requestTimeout: 300000,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      connectionsCheckingInterval: 30000,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      noDelay: true,
      keepAlive: false,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 11,
      [Symbol(http.server.connections)]: ConnectionsList {},
      [Symbol(http.server.connectionsCheckingInterval)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 2510,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound checkConnections],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 30000,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 10,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
      },
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      requestTimeout: 300000,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      connectionsCheckingInterval: 30000,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      noDelay: true,
      keepAlive: false,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 0,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
      _connectionKey: '6::::3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 11,
      [Symbol(http.server.connections)]: ConnectionsList {},
      [Symbol(http.server.connectionsCheckingInterval)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 2510,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound checkConnections],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 30000,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 10,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1
      },
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': null,
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [IncomingMessage],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 124,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
    [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
    [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
  },
  _header: null,
  _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
  _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
  req: IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: null,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      constructed: true,
      sync: true,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: true,
      dataEmitted: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 124,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: false,
    rawHeaders: [
      'my-custom-header',
      'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySW5mbyI6InVzZXIxN0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ0aW1lT2ZDcmVhdGlvbiI6IjIwMjQtMDQtMDNUMjI6Mjc6MjYuMzczWiIsInVzZXJJZCI6IjY2MDZmYTg2ZmI0OGE0YmM5NmQxMTY1ZSIsImlhdCI6MTcxMjE4MzI0NiwiZXhwIjoxNzEyMjE1NjQ2fQ.5CW40ajYsHcMIuH7MfHh1yYMwwcFx6mv97GSrDjojb4',
      'Authorization',
      'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYxM2ZjMzY2Y2EwMDYyODA5OTRkZGI5NiIsIm5pY2tuYW1lIjoidGVzdDEiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODEwMjc3NDcsImV4cCI6MTY4MTAzMTI0N30.xZ1c_aFk5WbmrMAEa7dQVoLd5GIwqHPha7CewxoyiVc',
      'User-Agent',
      'PostmanRuntime/7.37.0',
      'Postman-Token',
      '69f84774-467b-4c3f-ab67-c2adac534169',
      'Host',
      'localhost:3000',
      'Content-Length',
      '0'
    ],
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '/disable_user/65da6703ba4aacef21563c4d',
    method: 'PUT',
    statusCode: null,
    statusMessage: null,
    client: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      setEncoding: [Function: socketSetEncoding],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *2],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 124,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    _consuming: false,
    _dumped: false,
    next: [Function: next],
    baseUrl: '/gossipi/users',
    originalUrl: '/gossipi/users/disable_user/65da6703ba4aacef21563c4d',
    _parsedUrl: Url {
      protocol: null,
      slashes: null,
      auth: null,
      host: null,
      port: null,
      hostname: null,
      hash: null,
      search: null,
      query: null,
      pathname: '/disable_user/65da6703ba4aacef21563c4d',
      path: '/disable_user/65da6703ba4aacef21563c4d',
      href: '/disable_user/65da6703ba4aacef21563c4d',
      _raw: '/disable_user/65da6703ba4aacef21563c4d'
    },
    params: { userId: '65da6703ba4aacef21563c4d' },
    query: {},
    res: [Circular *2],
    body: {},
    route: Route {
      path: '/disable_user/:userId',
      stack: [Array],
      methods: [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kHeaders)]: {
      'my-custom-header': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySW5mbyI6InVzZXIxN0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ0aW1lT2ZDcmVhdGlvbiI6IjIwMjQtMDQtMDNUMjI6Mjc6MjYuMzczWiIsInVzZXJJZCI6IjY2MDZmYTg2ZmI0OGE0YmM5NmQxMTY1ZSIsImlhdCI6MTcxMjE4MzI0NiwiZXhwIjoxNzEyMjE1NjQ2fQ.5CW40ajYsHcMIuH7MfHh1yYMwwcFx6mv97GSrDjojb4',
      authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYxM2ZjMzY2Y2EwMDYyODA5OTRkZGI5NiIsIm5pY2tuYW1lIjoidGVzdDEiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODEwMjc3NDcsImV4cCI6MTY4MTAzMTI0N30.xZ1c_aFk5WbmrMAEa7dQVoLd5GIwqHPha7CewxoyiVc',
      'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.37.0',
      'postman-token': '69f84774-467b-4c3f-ab67-c2adac534169',
      host: 'localhost:3000',
      'content-length': '0'
    },
    [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 12,
    [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
    [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
  },
  _sent100: false,
  _expect_continue: false,
  _maxRequestsPerSocket: 0,
  locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: false,
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    '0': [ '0', 'm' ],
    '1': [ '1', 'y' ],
    '2': [ '2', '-' ],
    '3': [ '3', 'c' ],
    '4': [ '4', 'u' ],
    '5': [ '5', 's' ],
    '6': [ '6', 't' ],
    '7': [ '7', 'o' ],
    '8': [ '8', 'm' ],
    '9': [ '9', '-' ],
    '10': [ '10', 'h' ],
    '11': [ '11', 'e' ],
    '12': [ '12', 'a' ],
    '13': [ '13', 'd' ],
    '14': [ '14', 'e' ],
    '15': [ '15', 'r' ],
    'x-powered-by': [ 'X-Powered-By', 'Express' ]
  },
  [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
} headers   headers get undefined


This is the method included in the class:

import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { ExceptionHandlerClass } from "../../root-exception-handlers/exceptions-database-handler/exception-handlers.exception";
import JWTClass from "../../root-helpers/jwt/jwt.helpers";


const ERROR_EXCEPTION_HANDLER =
  ExceptionHandlerClass.getExceptionHandlerInstance();
const TOKEN_HELPER = JWTClass.getJWTHelperInstance();

export default class JWTMiddlewareClass {
  private static jwtMiddlewareInstance: JWTMiddlewareClass;

  public static getJWTMiddlewareInstance(): JWTMiddlewareClass {
    if (!this.jwtMiddlewareInstance) {
      this.jwtMiddlewareInstance = new JWTMiddlewareClass();
    }

    return this.jwtMiddlewareInstance;
  }

  public jwtValidatorMiddleware(
    response: Response,
    request: Request,
    next: NextFunction
  ): void {
    const availableToken = request.header("my-custom-header");



    console.log(
      "my token",
      availableToken,
      "headers ",
      request.headers ? request.headers["my-custom-header"] : "",
      "headers get",
      request.get("my-custom-header")
    );
   ... other stuffs
  }
}


But not sure why still I´m not able to access the specific header info
my postman request is done ok

Any help would be great!!
